# check if multiple bash arrays are gt 0

Tags: arrays, bash

I currently have 3 arrays, checking if subdirectories have `.py`, `.java`, .js etc

```
jsfilearray=(`find ./ -maxdepth 10 -name "*.js"`)
javafilearray=(`find ./ -maxdepth 10 -name "*.java"`)
pyfilearray=(`find ./ -maxdepth 10 -name "*.py"`)
```

How can I compare if `jsfilearray` or `javafilearray` or `pyfilearray` havent found any files?

I'm currently do it for just one array, with:
`if [ ${#jsfilearray[@]} -gt 0 ]; then`

How can I do it all in one condition for the 3 arrays?

Thanks

Comment: Use `||`, just like in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youc an also combine all 3 arrays into one and then check the size. Something like this:

```
declare -a allFiles

allFiles+=( "${pyfilearray[@]}" "${javafilearray[@]}" "${jsfilearray[@]}" )

if [[ ${#allFiles[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then ..
```

---

If you only checking the size for all three file types. You can make the find command search for multiple exts:

```
allfiles=$(find . -iregex '.*\.\(py\|\|java\|js\)$')

if [[ ${#allFiles[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then ..
```

Comment: Gosh this is clever, to me at least anyways. i like your second snippet

Comment: Should I also be using the `declare` line in the second snippet?

Comment: That is just an explicit way to declare an array.

Answer (score 1):

You will have an issue if there are spaces in any of the file names. Better to create the arrays with i.e.:

```
 readarray -t jsfilearray <<< "$(find ./ -maxdepth 10 -name "*.js")"
```

This will take each line of the output from find and use this as the array values.

You can then check if all array are greater than 0 with:

```
if [[ ${#jsfilearray[@]} -gt 0 && ${#javafilearray[@]} -gt 0 && ${#pyfilearray[@]} -gt 0 ]]
then
     .....
fi
```

Comment: and missed a `#` like `${#jsfilearray[@]}`

Comment: Apologies. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As in many programming languages you can combine multiple checks with the boolean operators `&&` (and) and `||` (or).

```
if [ "${#jsfilearray[@]}" = 0 ] ||
   [ "${#javafilearray[@]}" = 0 ] ||
   [ "${#pyfilearray[@]}" = 0 ]
then
    echo "At least one array is empty"
else
    echo "All arrays contain something"
fi
```